# heroku app wont start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, error-handling

My app  is down, and I'm not sure what the server is complaining about this time. Can anyone clue me in? Logs below:

```
    2012-08-29T02:03:00+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 36518`
2012-08-29T02:03:05+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-08-29T02:03:05+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.6 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:36518
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': /app/app/controllers/groups_controller.rb:55: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end (SyntaxError)
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on'
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:4:in `require'
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `new'
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ra
ilties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `require'
2012-08-29T02:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2012-08-29T02:03:09+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-08-29T02:03:09+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-08-29T02:13:19+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2012-08-29T02:13:21+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 41178`
2012-08-29T02:13:26+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-08-29T02:13:26+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.6 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:41178
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': /app/app/controllers/groups_controller.rb:55: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end (SyntaxError)
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on'
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:4:in `require'
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `new'
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `require'
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2012-08-29T02:13:28+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2012-08-29T02:13:29+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-08-29T02:13:29+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-08-29T02:13:53+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET sleepy-sands-3221.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-08-29T02:13:53+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET sleepy-sands-3221.herokuapp.com/fa

vicon.ico dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in your code, you may have not noticed in development because you didnt use or visited that controller, but heroku checks for errors before deploying and if anything is wrong with your code the whole application wont work. Check the /app/app/controllers/groups_controller.rb for syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing an "end" somewhere in your groups_controller.rb.  Check for un-ended code blocks.